# How do I make a method in a class change the variables in another class?

Tags: c#

```
class Enemy
{
    public int Health = 100;
    public int AttackDamage = 20;
    
}

class Player
{
    public int Health = 100;
    public int AttackDamage = 20;
    
}
```

I want to write a method which decreases `Player.Health` by `Enemy.AttackDamage`
how do I access the variables from class Player from a method in class Enemy

I am still learning the basics and I cant find a solution for this I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain to me how I can do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to have instance both player and enemy ... and then ... then you just use fields ... SO is not a good place for learning of programming basics ... because it's hard to assume what you know (for example if you know what is the difference between class and its instance) and what you don't

Comment: Either create an instance of Player within the method in Enemy, or perhaps more logically, if the player already exists, pass an existing instance of Player into the method (or inject it into the class via the constructor). It really depends...we don't have sufficient context...but basically you need to make sure there's a suitable instance of Player in scope when the method runs. Does that help? Your precise scenario is unclear and it's also not very clear exactly how/why you're stuck, or whether you've actually attempted anything. See also [ask] for more guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all we expect that both player and enemy could shoot each other.
If so then we have to create base class `Shooter` who have `health`, `damage` and can perform shot to lower health of the target.

```
class Shooter
{
    public int health;
    public int attackDamage;
    public Shooter(int health,int attackDamage)
    {
        this.health=health;
        this.attackDamage = attackDamage;
    }
    public void Shoot(Shooter target)
    {
        target.health-=this.attackDamage;
    }
}
```

Here we created class constructor `public Shooter()` and method `Shoot()`.
`Constructor` assigns HP and damage to new unit.
Method `Shoot` gets target and applies damage on him.

Now we need to imlement `Player` and `Enemy` classes which inherits our base class `Shooter`.

```
class Player:Shooter
{
    public string name;
    public Player(string name,int damage):base(100,damage)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }
    public new void Shoot(Shooter target)
    {
        base.Shoot(target);
        Console.WriteLine(
            String.Format("Player {0} hit enemy for {1} damage and left him {2} HP",
                          this.name,
                          this.attackDamage,
                          target.health));
    }
}
class Enemy:Shooter
{
    public Enemy(int damage):base(100,damage)
    {
            
    }
}
```

To make our program a bit more representative I've extentded `Shoot` method to show that our Player dealt some damage to the enemy.

Finally we need our method `Main()` to show the interaction between classes.

```
public static void Main()
{
    Player me = new Player("Rambo",15);
    Enemy enemy = new Enemy(10);
    me.Shoot(enemy);
    me.Shoot(enemy);
    me.Shoot(enemy);
    
}
```

You can see and test my example here https://dotnetfiddle.net/ofgqw2